# iOS: MPMoviePlayer, remove from its superview

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, mpmovieplayer

Once added, I would like to know if it is possible to remove a movie player from its superview. I've searched a lot but I haven't found any solution yet. In particular, I would remove the player when the user tap on end button.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use code like this :

```
[thePlayer.view removeFromSuperview];
```

Answer (score 0):

[videoPlayer stop];
[videoPlayer removeFromSuperview];